# jQuery Autoselect not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I've been trying to fire the event of autoselect using jquery.. It works in a way where it actually it shouldn't work. I don't understand what's going on. It was supposed to work as per the documentation.

Code that works

```
$('.carComplete').autocomplete(
   "/autoComplete.html?ajax=true&type=CAR"
);
```

Code that doesn't work

```
$('.carComplete').autocomplete({
   source:"/autoComplete.html?ajax=true&type=CAR"
});
```

Is there any wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL must point to a JSON or JSONP, not HTML.